# Python Django fix " NOT NULL constraint failed: pages_login.username "

Tags: python, django

I was having a problem with send data like(username, password) to the **Django administration** so after several tries I found I very simple fixes, which I will put it here.

**First My Html Source:**

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}


{% block content %}
<form method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <br>
    <input placeholder="username" type="text" name="username"><br>
    <br><input placeholder="Password" type="password" name="password">
    <br><input type="submit" value="save">
</form>
{% endblock content %}
```

**Second My models.py file :**

```
from django.db import models
class Login(models.Model):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

**Third And the important important thing and here You will get the fix GO TO VIWES.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import Login
def Test(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':

        username = request.POST.get('username')
        password = request.POST.get('password')

        form = Login(username=username, password=password)
        form.save()
return render(request, 'pages/about.html', )
```

***return*** **should be out of (if)**

Comment: post full error message

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read about [asking questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking). It is unclear if you are asking a question, or presenting a fix. If you want to share a solution you should first ask a question and then self post an answer to that same question.